# How to supply authentication to firebase-import?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I would like to import a json file into my Firebase database. I tried [firebase-import](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-import) as follows:

```
$ firebase-import --firebase_url https://mytest.firebaseio.com/ --json test.json
```

but I am getting a "Permission denied" error.

I know that firebase-import has --auth option, which says "Specify an auth token to use (e.g. your Firebase Secret)". How do I get an auth token or my Firebase Secret?

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you need to create a service account (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup) and the provide the service account JSON to `firebase-import` using the `--service_account` command-line option.

Answer (score 0):

Create New Project.
Click Add App
Add Firebase to your web app.
this code will show up

```
 <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
      var config = {
        **apiKey: "<API_KEY>",**
        authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>
```

that is you API key then add -a API_KEY
so you will have

```
firebase-import --firebase_url https://test.firebaseio-demo.com --json test.json --merge -a API_KEY
```

Comment: The API key does not work. Note that the API key is public, so it should allow changing of the database in such a major way.